# wordpress form processing to custom post type not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to insert a custom post type for a multiple image upload form.  The below code is the form processing.  The page is blank when i submit the form.  Where did i go wrong?

```
   $art_title = $_POST['art_title'];

    $i = 0;
    foreach($art_title as $value) {
    $art_title = $_POST['art_title'][$i];
    $art_width = $_POST['art_width'][$i];
    $art_height = $_POST['art_height'][$i];
    $art_price = $_POST['art_price'][$i];
    $art_creation_date = $_POST['art_creation_date'][$i];
    $art_upload = $_FILES['art_upload'][$i];

    $_SESSION['saved_art_form']['art_title'][$i] = $art_title;
    $_SESSION['saved_art_form']['art_width'][$i] = $art_width;
    $_SESSION['saved_art_form']['art_height'][$i] = $art_height;
    $_SESSION['saved_art_form']['art_price'][$i] = $art_price;
    $_SESSION['saved_art_form']['art_creation_date'][$i] = $art_creation_date;


         $post = array(
          'post_content'   => '', // The full text of the post.
          'post_name'      => $art_title, // The name (slug) for your post
          'post_title'     => $art_title, // The title of your post.
          'post_status'    => 'draft', // Default 'draft'.
          'post_type'      => 'products', // Default 'post'.
          'post_author'    => '', // The user ID number of the author. Default is the current user ID.
          'menu_order'     => '0', // If new post is a page, sets the order in which it should appear in supported menus. Default 0.
          'post_password'  => '', // Password for post, if any. Default empty string.
          'post_excerpt'   => '', // For all your post excerpt needs.
          'comment_status' => 'open' , // Default is the option 'default_comment_status', or 'closed'.
          'post_category'  => '' // Default empty.
        ); 
        $post_id = wp_insert_post( $post); 
        wp_set_post_categories( $post_id);
        add_post_meta($post_id, '_width', $art_width, true);
        add_post_meta($post_id, '_height', $art_height, true);

        $filename = $_FILES["art_upload"][[$i]["name"];
        $uploads = wp_upload_dir();

        //file_put_contents($file, $image_data);
        $file_array = array(
                'name'          => $_FILES['art_upload'][$i]['name'],
                'type'          => $_FILES['art_upload'][$i]['type'],
                'tmp_name'      => $_FILES['art_upload'][$i]['tmp_name'],
                'error'         => $_FILES['art_upload'][$i]['error'],
                'size'          => $_FILES['art_upload'][$i]['size']
        );

        // required for wp_handle_upload() to upload the file
        $upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => FALSE );

        if ( !empty( $file_array['name'] ) ) {
           // upload the file to the server
            $uploaded_file = wp_handle_upload( $file_array, $upload_overrides );

                // checks the file type and stores in in a variable
            $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype( basename( $uploaded_file['art_upload'] ), null );       
               // set up the array of arguments for "wp_insert_post();"
            $attachment = array(

                'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
                'post_title' => preg_replace('/.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $uploaded_file['art_upload'] ) ),
                'post_content' => '',
                'post_author' => '',
                'post_status' => 'inherit',
                'post_type' => 'attachment',
                'guid' => $uploads['url'] . '/' . $file_array['name']
            );

            // insert the attachment post type and get the ID
            $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename, $post_id );
            $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $uploaded_file['art_upload'] );
            require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
            // update the attachment metadata
            wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id,  $attach_data );
            $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id );
            set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $post_thumbnail_id );
        }







    $i++;
    }
```

Comment: You should turn on debugging to properly evaluate the error.

Comment: I added error_reporting(E_ALL); but still blank page?

Comment: Before `error_reporting(E_ALL)`, add `ini_set('display_errors', true);`

Comment: How about [WP_DEBUG](http://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG)?

Comment: No. define('WP_DEBUG', false); this to define('WP_DEBUG', true); in  wp_config.php file.

Comment: I did this.. but the art_form_process.php page is still blank.  Errors are showing on other pages, so wp_debug is on.  Is there anything you can see why the custom post isn't being inserted?

Comment: when i remove the php the page redirects with no processing. With the php no page redirect.  wp_debug or error_reporting just shows a blank page no errors.

Comment: Do i need to require any files?